# Particular Nim game variant (2 or 3 sticks)

Tags: algorithm, tree, greedy

You start with a stack of n sticks. Each player removes 2 or 3 sticks each turn. The player who removes the last stick wins. If their is only one stick left, the game is a draw.

I need to determine who will win a game of n stacks in general, expressed as a function of n. However, unless we start the game with 2, 3 or 5 sticks, it is always possible to direct the game so that it ends in a draw. I drew the game tree for 9 sticks and more and it is always possible to prevent a loss by making choices that lead to one stick remaining. How can I write a winning rule for this given problem?

Answer (score 1):

> However, unless we start the game with 2, 3 or 5 sticks, it is always possible to direct the game so that it ends in a draw.

I don't think this is true.

For example, suppose we start with 10 sticks.  If you remove x sticks, I will always remove 5-x sticks.  This will mean that after one turn each there are 5 sticks left, and after two turns each I have won.

The same will apply for any multiple of 5.

Now consider other possible values modulo 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the rule:

- Losing Position: n = 5k
- Draw: n = 5k+1 or n = 5k+4
- Winning Position: n = 5k+2 or n = 5k+3

You can observe the pattern by building a table like the one shown below:

**0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 .....**

**L D W W D L D W W D L D W W D L D**

Steps for Building the table:

1. Observe that you lose if **n = 0**, mark it as **L**.
2. When **n = 1**, it is draw, mark it as **D**.
3. When **n = 2**, you can only draw 2 sticks. So, your opponent happens to face n=0 which is losing, so you win, mark it as **W**.
4. For **n = 3**, you can take 2 or 3 sticks, so, your opponent can end up at 1 or 0 sticks. 1 is a **draw** and 0 is **loss** for him and therefore win for us. So, we will chose win, mark it as **W**.
5. For **n=4**, similarily, opponent can end up at 2 or 1. So, we can draw or lose. We will choose draw, mark it as **D**.
6. For **n = 5**, we can either make our opponent end up at 2 or 3. Both of them are **win** for him. So, we lose. Mark it as **L**.

Basically, to determine the state(**L, W or D**) of a number **n**, we need to look at states of already computed states **n-2** and **n-3**.

Observe that this pattern (***LDWWD***) repeats after that.